# inner join con count y/o sum en mysql

Tags: mysql

en mysql Tengo dos tablas, "estudiantes" y "tutores", donde un tutor tiene varios estudiantes, y cada tutor tiene asignado un area (matematicas, espanol, ingles etc)

Lo que necesito es una sentencia para contar el número de estudiantes que tienen tutoría con cada area, por ejemplo (segun los datos de ejemplo de la imagen):

matematicas: 8 (ya que se cuentan los estudiantes del tutor 1 y los del tutor 4 que son los de matematicas)
espanol: 4 (ya que solo los estudiantes del tutor 2 estudian espanol)

y así por cada materia, he intentado pero no me ha funcionado un inner join con count y/o sum, les agradezco enormemente ya que es muy importante para mí, muchas gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto debería resolver tu pregunta:

```
SELECT T.area, 
       IFNULL(COUNT(E.nombre_estudiante),0) 'Cantidad'
       FROM tutores T
       LEFT JOIN estudiantes E
           ON E.cedula_tutor = T.cedula_tutor
       GROUP BY T.area
```

Básicamente, recuperamos los `tutores` agrupando por el `area` de estos y mediante un `LEFT JOIN` contamos los estudiantes de cada grupo. La idea del `LEFT` en vez de un `INNER` es la de poder ver también eventualmente aquellas `area` que no tuvieran estudiantes, en estos casos el `COUNT` retornará `NULL` por lo que si ese fuero el caso, con `IFNULL()` retornamos un `0` en vez de un `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

Realiza un conteo, sobre los campos de estudiante una vez realizado el join con tutores, y añade al final de tu sentencia SQL `group by area`.

Comment: Hola, como lo haría?, me da error combinar el count con inner join, menos poniendo group by al final, algo hago mal

Comment: Puedes agregar la sentencia que estas utilizando, o puedes probar con la publicada abajo.